# Install TeamViewer on Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Tags: 16.10, ubuntu-gnome, teamviewer

I'm trying to install TeamViewer on my computer, but I got the following message when I tried to launch the application :

[image]

Could anyone be able to tell me what do I have to do to fix this problem?